# How to import LinkedIn SDK in a Swift project?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, linkedin-api

I need to add the LinkedIn SDK into my Swift project. I've downloaded their latest version (1.0.4), dragged and dropped the SDK files into XCode (with "Copy items if needed" and "Add to target" checked). I can see the framework in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section of my target.

I'm stuck though when I need to import the headers in one swift file. There is an Objective C example in the LinkedIn documentation:

```
#import <linkedin-sdk/LISDK.h>
```

But how would you do it in Swift? I've tried different names but they all raise an error.

```
import LinkedIn
import LISDK
```

"import linkedin-sdk" fails because of the dash ( - ).

I've already imported external frameworks in my project (Parse for instance) and it perfectly worked.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**
I do not use LinkedIn API anymore, for they have stopped sharing useful information. Anyway, here is an old sample of code:

```
var accessToken: LISDKAccessToken?
func loadAccount(then: (() -> Void)?, or: ((String) -> Void)?) { // then & or are handling closures
    if let token = accessToken {
        LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAccessToken(token)
        if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {
            LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,headline,location,industry,current-share,num-connections,num-connections-capped,summary,specialties,positions,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))?format=json",
                success: {
                    response in
                    print(response.data)
                    then?()
                },
                error: {
                    error in
                    print(error)
                    or?("error")
                }
            )
        }
    } else {
        LISDKSessionManager.createSessionWithAuth([LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION], state: nil, showGoToAppStoreDialog: true,
            successBlock: {
                (state) in
                self.accessToken = LISDKSessionManager.sharedInstance().session.accessToken
                if LISDKSessionManager.hasValidSession() {
                    LISDKAPIHelper.sharedInstance().getRequest("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,headline,location,industry,current-share,num-connections,num-connections-capped,summary,specialties,positions,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))?format=json",
                        success: {
                            response in
                            print(response.data)
                            then?()
                        },
                        error: {
                            error in
                            print(error)
                            or?("error")
                        }
                    )
                }
            },
            errorBlock: {
                (error) in
                switch error.code {
                default:
                    if let errorUserInfo = error.userInfo["error"] as? NSString {
                        or?(errorUserInfo as String)
                    } else {
                        or?(UIError.Code.Unknown)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Helmikku, can you please post the  login code in swift.

Comment: Here you go. The second part of the function will open a session before getting user's linkedin's data. LinkedIn SDK will handle the process (open the LinkedIn app or the App Store if you do not have the app) and get back to the app with "successBlock". More information on their website: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk

Comment: The problem i am facing is , after getting the permission , its not coming  back to my app , and AppDelegate openURL method not getting called.

Comment: I cannot find the LinkedIn's page that describes the authentification's flow anymore, but I think there are cases where you are not redirected to your app (when LinkedIn App is not intalled or if you are not logged in). One last note, I remember I had troubles for I had skipped one or two lines of the docs (link in my previous comment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Man, you should have a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_80). Mine looks as simple as that:

```
//  Copyright © 2015 Arthur Gevorkyan. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef BridgingHeader_h
#define BridgingHeader_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <linkedin-sdk/LISDK.h>


#endif /* BridgingHeader_h */
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that Bridging was not necessary for importing external frameworks (as mentioned in the document from your link).

Comment: Sometimes things have "blurry" description in the Apple Docs. Have a good coding, man :)

Comment: Hi @Arthur I have just added  #import <linkedin-sdk/LISDK.h> in Bridging Header file but it shows file not found. Is this a perfect solution or need to add anything more ?

Comment: @dhavalrupani, the problem for you is that you've got your 'search paths' misconfigured in the project build setting. I would recommend you digging in that direction.