# Linkedin SDK architecture issue in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linkedin-api, undefined-symbol

I'm trying to use Linkedin SDK to auth in my iOS application, but when I build it i got this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LISDKCallbackHandler", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.LISDKCallbackHandler in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I'm using a bridging header where I'm importing the SDK to swift

```
#import <linkedin-sdk/LISDK.h>
```

and in my AppDelegate I have:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {


        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

        if LISDKCallbackHandler.shouldHandleUrl(url) {
            LISDKCallbackHandler.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Charles Lima Please refer this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34222196/how-to-import-linkedin-sdk-in-a-swift-project

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I forgot to set the Target Membership for the Framework package.
[setting the Target Membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7m5N.png)

Thanks